# LARAVEL 9 - Session conditions if admin or not

Tags: laravel, if-statement, laravel-9

I'm doing a Laravel 9 project and I would like to realize a user management.
I made a template with a basic header and I would like to know how to make a condition for this link (user management). If the session has an iduser with an administrator type, then I want it to show me the link. I show you my code :

```
<header>
    <div class="button-burger" id="button-burger">
        <button class="burger" id="button-burger">
            <img src="/img/icons/burger.png" alt="" class="burger" id="burger">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="bloc-logo">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/templates/logo.png') }}" alt="Fallout" class="bigger-logo">
    </div>
    <div class="bloc-links" id="bloc-links">
        <div class="link">
            <a href="/" class="linky">Accueil</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href="#" class="linky">Abris</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href="#" class="linky">Boutique</a>
        </div>
        <div id="nuka-link" class="link">
            <a href="/nuka-world" class="linky">Nuka World</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href="#" class="linky">Gestion d'utilisateur</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href="#" class="linky">Contact</a>
        </div>
        @if (Session::has('iduser'))
            <div class="link">
                <a href="/mon-profil" class="linky">Mon profil</a>
            </div>
            <div class="link">
                <a href="/deconnexion" class="linky">Déconnexion</a>
            </div>
        @else
            <div class="link">
                <a href="/connexion" class="linky">Se connecter</a>
            </div>
        @endif

    </div>
</header>
```

How can I do that please ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can retrieve the user id through `request()->user()->id` to check if the user is an admin. Or you can create an `isAdmin()` method in your User model  to see if an user is an admin and then call it this way:

`@if(request()->user()->isAdmin())`

Comment: Excuse me for my late answer but it works perfectly thank you :D

Comment: No problem :) , can you mark my comment as the solving answer?